# How to select more than one field values in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
+--------------+------------+-------------+-------------+
|     uid      | latitude   | longitude   |   regid     |
+--------------+------------+-------------+-------------+
|      1       |  73.3433   |  18.5223    |APA91W-ClDoS |
|              |            |             |             |
+--- ----------+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Suppose this is database table, now what i want is to select more than one field values `latitude`, `longitude` and `regid`. So the query which i am using it is returning only first field value.

This is the query i am trying, and it is returning only first field value which is `73.3433`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT latitude, longitude, regid FROM gps WHERE uid = 1 ");
        $tagID = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $keys = array_keys($tagID);
        for($i=0;$i<count($tagID);$i++){
            return $tagID[$keys[$i]];
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT latitude, longitude, regid FROM gps WHERE uid = 1 ");

while ($resultRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($resultRow['latitude']); 
    print_r($resultRow['longitude']); 
    print_r($resultRow['regid']);  
}
```

OR try:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT latitude, longitude, regid FROM gps WHERE uid = 1 ");

while ($resultRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($resultRow);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only selecting the values from a Column that has UID equal to 1.

If you want to select everything you could try with the following query.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT latitude, longitude, regid FROM gps");
```